# Getting difference between subtotal and individual row values in powerbi dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to get a solution to below problem in powerbi dax

```
Area  Jan  Feb  Mar   Total
1     2.92 2.97 3.31  3.06
    A 2.91 2.95 3.00  2.97
    B 2.88 2.90 3.22  3.05
    C 2.95 2.98 3.32  3.15
```

Want to get the difference to read

```
Area  Jan  Feb  Mar   Total
1     2.92 2.97 3.31   3.06
    A 0.01 0.02 -0.31  -0.09
    B -0.04 -0.07 -0.09  -0.01
    C 0.03 0.01 0.01  0.09
```

Kindly assist how one would go about in powerbi dax.

Comment: Your expected output is unclear, please elaborate.

Comment: How does one know that area A, B, or C, are children (that is, they are subcategories) of "Area 1?"  I ask because I assume your data likely contains an "Area 2" with some number of children D, E, and F.  This would be considerably easier if all 'child' rows specifically referenced their 'parent' row.  Also, we would want some kind of method to identify if a row is a parent or a child.  This structure can be built out using power query, but will always involve some guessing based on rules.

Comment: @RyanB.Thanks Ryan. What I want to achieve is from the first table the second row is the averages of A,B,C in those months so I need to get the deviation of the values in A,B,C from the mean month like what is represented in expected table. More like getting the difference of child values from parent values.

Comment: Please show someraw data in table, Then I know what DAX to write..

Answer (score 0):

I have unpivoted your first table and used the following Calculated column to arrive at the requested results.

```
Difference = IF('Data'[Area]="1",'Data'[Value],'Data'[Value] - LOOKUPVALUE('Data'[Value],'Data'[Attribute],'Data'[Attribute],'Data'[Area],"1"))
```

Sanpshot of the result[image: Snapshot]